# Spring Data Mongodb: remove String from Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection named **pub**. Each document contains a array of strings named **cocktails**, So that :

```
{"id" : "0", "name" : "My Beautiful Pub", "cocktails" : ["B52", "SexOnTheBeach", "Negroni"]}
```

Using Spring mongodb, I would delete every "SexOnTheBeach", so that :

```
{"id" : "0", "name" : "My Beautiful Pub", "cocktails" : ["B52", "Negroni"]}
```

... every pub document in my "pub" collection cannot contain the "SexOnTheBeach".

I think I should use the `new Update().pull()` method, but every update doesn't modify my db.

This mongodb query works perfectly, but I don't know how to translate it!

```
db.pub.update(
{ },
{ $pull: {  cocktails: "SexOnTheBeach" } },
{ multi: true })
```

Ty in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `@Service` class, add:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;

@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

...

mongoTemplate.updateMulti(new Query(), new Update().pull("cocktails", "SexOnTheBeach"), "pub");
```

Comment: TY, perfect solution!